# How do I draw a line between two ImageButtons in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a line between 2 ImageButtons on screen.  I have the buttons placed on the screen in an xml file and I am trying to code a way to draw a set of lines that will correctly scale when I use a different screen size.  When I try to use getX() it states that the returned values are all 0.  Is there some way I'm missing to get the x and y values of where I placed the buttons in the xml?  Do I have to put the line in manually for each different screen size?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {

    }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        size = 0;
        View v = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.minor_fragment_two, container,     false);
        final ImageButton one = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.one);
        final ImageButton two = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.two);
        final ImageButton three = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.three);
        final ImageButton four = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.four);
        final ImageButton five = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.five);
        final ImageButton six = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.six);
        final ImageButton seven = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.seven);
        final ImageButton eight = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.eight);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imView);
        //Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Display currentDisplay = ((WindowManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
        float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        onex = one.getX();
        oney = one.getY();
        twox = two.getX();
        twoy = two.getY();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Position :" + onex + " " + oney + " " + twox + " " + twoy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        canvas.drawLine(onex,oney,twox,twoy,paint);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        //return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.minor_fragment_two, container, false);
        return v;
    }    


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/reduced"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imView"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can get width and height of display programmatically and set your images and draw lines by geomethrical position

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying.  Sorry, I may have asked the question in an unclear way.  My problem is that I cannot get the locations of the buttons I am placing in the xml file and I would like to draw a line connecting each button to the next based on their location in the xml.  Currently when I try to get them programmatically they are returning the coordinates (0,0) for all buttons and I am not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a line by adding a view to your xml.

Vertical line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
/>
```

Horizontal line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
/>
```

Adjust the background color to your desired line color.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  My problem now is that I am trying to draw this line to connect the two imageButtons together one pair at a time, but the program currently returns the locations of all the buttons as (0,0).  How would I go about getting the locations that I placed the buttons in the xml file?

Comment: For others' benefit, please accept this answer and ask a new question for getting the location of a view.